# How to create directory from a stored procedure on an Oracle server machine?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I can create directory as follows from SQL Developer or sqlplus:

```
host mkdir "/path/to/dir"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do it in a stored procedure when the directory name is an input or generated inside the procedure.

For example for this procedure:

```
Create Procedure Create_dir (dir_name IN varchar2) As
Begin
  execute immediate 'host mkdir "' || dir_name || '"'
End;
```

when I run:

```
exec Create_dir ('c:\temp\test');
```

I get error:

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

And this one:

```
Create Procedure Create_dir (dir_name IN varchar2) As
Begin
  host ('mkdir "' || dir_name || '"')
End;
```

Causes a compile error

> identifier 'HOST' must be declared.

Is there a simple way too do it?

Comment: `host` is a SQL*Plus command.  Not a SQL or PL/SQL command.  It would create `host mkdir` would create an operating system directory on the client machine.  You could create a stored procedure that invoked a Java class which created an operating system directory on the server machine.  But a stored procedure would have no way to create a directory on the client machine.  Only an application running on the client could do that.

Comment: I want to create the dir on the server machine not on the client machine.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate post, here's an example of a Java stored procedure that calls out to the host operating system https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241